A manhwa in which the main character is sent to a distant outpost
The main character is reborn in the body of a child and is sent to a distant outpost, where the male character at first thinks of killing her, but then becomes attached and they become like father and daughter, and in future chapters he asks to call her father

Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Hello. No, but the man seemed to have white or blue hair.

The main character is a young girl, correct? Any idea about how old she is? Like 10, 16, 21, anything along those lines? How old is the father figure - 20s? 30s? 60s? What is this "distant outpost" - a battlefield, or a fort/castle near one? Does this take place in a snowy area?
